# Reset GDPR/Consent Dialog (Opt back in after revoking consent)

Tags: android, mopub, gdprconsentform

I am integrating MoPub and am testing the GDPR consent dialog flow. I have it working successfully and a user can grant or revoke access using the standard MoPub consent dialog.

However, I have included an option in the app settings to manually revoke consent using the PersonalInfoManager.revokeConsent() method. Having done this I can never get the consent dialog to show again.

If a user wants to opt back in after revoking consent, how can they do this?

Previously, I used Google AdMob and after uninstalling and reinstalling the app the consent dialog would show again. This isn't the case with MoPub - the consent choice seems to persist somewhere.

Is there a way to clear MoPub's consent information so it shows the consent dialog again?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MoPub has static method for that ready for you.

```
MoPub.getPersonalInformationManager().revokeConsent()
```